# Overlapping rotated images in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the arrows to start at the exact same point and vary the rotations of the arrows. Below is an example of my code in HTML/JS/CSS and a picture of what i am running into. Any ideas as to how to make the pictures of these arrows overlap better at the origin?

HTML/JS

```
content.innerHTML= '<div id = "contain"><img class = "arrow" style="transform: rotate(90deg)" src="img/arrow_0]+'.png"</img><img class = "arrow" style="transform: rotate(60deg)" src="img/arrow_1.png"</img><img class = "arrow" style="transform: rotate(75deg)" src="img/arrow.png"</img></div>'
```

CSS:

```
#contain {
    position: relative;
    width: 104%;
    height: 132%;
}

#contain img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.arrow {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position:absolute;
}
```

[image: Two arrows not meeting at center]

[image: 3 arrows, black seems to align]

Any pointers appreciated many thanks!!

Comment: Could you put up a working snippet which has the actual pngs in it - I see that they are not all the same width and you will want to transform their origins to the same point (I think that's what you are after, so they all pivot as though a nail was put through them all).

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is because the container size & then the transform-origin is at 0%, where as 50% from the top would work better.

```css
.arrow {
  width: 200px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}
#contain-1 .arrow { background-color: red; transform: rotate(90deg); }
#contain-2 .arrow { background-color: green; transform: rotate(45deg); }
#contain-3 .arrow { background-color: blue }
```

```html
<div id="contain-1">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="contain-2">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="contain-3">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
 </div>
```